# How to deal with different stylesheets (WYSIWYG Editor and Webpage one) in the same page?

Tags: html, css, wysiwyg

Due to validation markup and some other reasons I disable the `list-style-type` css property in order to build the website navigation.

I'm using MCEeditor for generating text content and I had to create a list with `list-style-type: disc` css property inside it. The list appears correctly inside the text editor, but appears as my css said to appear (no list-style-type) in my website. I can't set `list-style-type: disc` either for obvious reasons (my menu navigation would mess up).

How can I let the bullets show up in my text content but at the same time hide my navigation list-style-type?

Comment: Without seeing your CSS we have no idea. This is a trivial problem if it isn't for the WYSIWYG editor getting in the way which is the problem with them writ large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS rules can be specific, for example:

```
.page-wrapper .inner
```

will apply rules to a specific subset of this css rule:

```
.page-wrapper
```

So you should specify the div which your WYSIWIG editor is in.

Answer (score 2):

give your navigation an id ( #nav) and only assign the list-style-type:none to that ID

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add another class to the `li` to separate it from the navigation and refer to it that way?